# How to remove the "My Account" menu item in a Lightning Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, community-builder

I don't want this "My Account" menu item in my Community:

[image: screen shot of offending menu]

This [post from Igor Androsov](http://iandrosov.github.io/Customize-Community-copy/) uses CSS to remove it:

```
.myAccount{
  display: none;  
}
```

but that no longer seems relevant in LWC-based Communities. I don't see any Community builder configuration to remove it.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong here, as I have never worked on communities, but how was

`.myAccount{ display:none; }`

working before. When i inspect element in my community page, i see each `menuitem` written as `home uiMenuItem`, `profile uiMenuItem`. Though I cannot see `My Account` as I dont have certain permissions.

[image]

But I went ahead and from [advanced setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_head.htm&type=5) of community builder edited the `Head Markup` to put this css.

```
<style>
    .profile.uiMenuItem{
      display: none;  
    }
</style>
```

And it hides the `My Profile` section from the menu, May be if you can change the profile to whatever class name account has, that might work.

Comment: The CSS selector that I found by inspection is `.profile-menuItem.myAccount` and that worked. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style>
    .profile.uiMenuItem{
      display: none;  
    }
    .myAccount.uiMenuItem{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```